# Terraform - Invalid template interpolation value

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use terraform to create an AnomalySubscription with AWS Cloudformation.
Based on: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-ce-anomalysubscription.html

When I tested Terraform plan, I'm receiving:

> ```
> │ Error: Invalid template interpolation value
>
>
> │     │ each.value.NotificationsEmail is tuple with 1 element
> │
> │ Cannot include the given value in a string template: string required.
> ```

*resource.tf*

```
resource "aws_cloudformation_stack" "anomaly_detection" {
  name = "${var.StackName}${each.value.Key}"

  for_each = { for i in local.anomalies : "${i.Key}" => i }

  template_body = <<EOF
  AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
  Description: Cost Anomaly Detection
  Resources:
    CostExplorer:
      Type: AWS::CE::AnomalySubscription
      Properties:
        Frequency: DAILY
        MonitorArnList: [!Ref CostExplorerServiceAnomalyMonitor]
        Subscribers: ${each.value.NotificationsEmail}
        SubscriptionName: DailyAnomalySubscription
        Threshold: ${each.value.Threshold}

EOF
}
```

```
locals {
  anomalies = flatten([
    for k, v in var.Anomalies : [
        {
          Key                    = k
          Type                   = v.Type
          NotificationsEmail     = v.NotificationsEmail
          Threshold              = v.Threshold
        }
    ]
  ])
}
```

```
Anomalies = {
  Subscription = {
    Type  = "Daily"
    Threshold = 500
    NotificationsEmail = [
      {
        Type = "EMAIL"
        Address = "test@xyz.com"
      },
      {
        Type = "EMAIL"
        Address = "test2@xyz.com"
      }]
  }
}
```

Based on:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-ce-anomalysubscription-subscriber.html

```
    NotificationsEmail = [
      {
        Type = "EMAIL"
        Address = "test@xyz.com"
      },
      {
        Type = "EMAIL"
        Address = "test2@xyz.com"
      }]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An heredoc structure is always a string, this is why terraform complains that it cannot interpolate your tuple.

Since what you are actually feeding in the heredoc is YAML document, you can encode your tuple to YAML using [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html).

Why JSON encode? As pointed in the documentation, YAML is just a superset of JSON:

> `yamlencode` always uses YAML's "block style" for mappings and sequences, unless the mapping or sequence is empty. To generate flow-style YAML, use [`jsonencode`](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/jsonencode.html) instead: YAML flow-style is a superset of JSON syntax.

*<sup>Source: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/yamlencode.html</sup>*

---

Given a simplified:

```hcl
variable "NotificationsEmail" {
  default = {
    Type = "EMAIL"
    Address = "test2@xyz.com"
  }
}

output "test" {
  value = <<EOF
  AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
  Description: Cost Anomaly Detection
  Resources:
    CostExplorer:
      Type: AWS::CE::AnomalySubscription
      Properties:
        Frequency: DAILY
        MonitorArnList: [!Ref CostExplorerServiceAnomalyMonitor]
        Subscribers: ${jsonencode(var.NotificationsEmail)}
        SubscriptionName: DailyAnomalySubscription
  EOF
}
```

This yields the expected:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Description: Cost Anomaly Detection
Resources:
  CostExplorer:
    Type: AWS::CE::AnomalySubscription
    Properties:
      Frequency: DAILY
      MonitorArnList: [!Ref CostExplorerServiceAnomalyMonitor]
      Subscribers: {"Address":"test2@xyz.com","Type":"EMAIL"}
      SubscriptionName: DailyAnomalySubscription
```

Which is a perfectly valid YAML document.

Comment: Thanks! It works perfectly with the template.

Comment: How to pass the value by the parameters?   
parameters = {
    NotificationsEmail = "${jsonencode(each.value.NotificationsEmail)}"
    Threshold          = each.value.Threshold
  } is getting jsonencode as a string

Comment: Well, yes, here you are back in a `.tf` file with variable and tuples from the look of your structure, so you do not need to `jsonencode` anymore. `parameters = { NotificationsEmail = each.value.NotificationsEmail Threshold = each.value.Threshold }`

Comment: @headincl0ud If it worked, then the answer should be accepted.

Comment: Jasne @Marcin, I was pretty sure that you will be first in this topic, best wishes for you from Wroclaw :)

Comment: @β.εηοιτ.βε thanks for your help in this case!

Comment: @headincl0ud 10 hours too late:-) Pozdrawiam.

Comment: so if you want only "Address" for example, is this going to work? `Subscribers: ${jsonencode(var.NotificationsEmail)}[Address]`